# How to call the subroutine from another perl module using threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am trying for thread programming perl in a following way:

`Description:`
The current perl script needs to call another subroutine exists in the another perl module(.pm file) using thread method.

`Case1:` general way of callign subroutine using threads is like

```
my $t= Thread->new(\&process, @args);
```

where process is the subroutine exists in the same perl file.

`Case2:` calling the subroutine which exists in a different perl module

```
my $t= Thread->new(\&$anotherfile->another_process, @args);
```

where another_process exists in the different perl module and not in the same perl file.

Question is that `Case2` is not working for me. I am not able pass any arguments to this thread.
Can any one helpme to solve this issue?

Comment: First you should `use` or `require` package from another file, and point to it's methods via package. Your `Thread` is old and deprecated thread model; which perl version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

because case 2 give to thread reference of return from method another_process on varibale anotherfile...

try used closure:

```
threads->create(
    sub {
        return $anotherfile->another_process(@_);
    },
    @args
);
```